# Why does my workstation fall asleep when I am connected to it via Remote Desktop Services?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, sleep

So, I have a workstation at work, a Thinkpad. It runs Windows 10 Pro and according to the Balanced power policy, should sleep after 30 minutes when plugged in.

I am now connecting to it remotely from home, via Microsoft's Remote Desktop infrastructure.

The workstation cannot be reached over RDS directly, but is behind an RDS gateway server. I neither know much about the latter nor its setup.

What I don't understand -- and I have also tried setting the sleep timeout to "never" in power settings -- is why does the workstation fall asleep after mere minutes of inactivity over RDS?

The event log contains a bunch of messages every third minute about it falling asleep and waking up. It doesn't sleep when I do things on it, and it didn't fall asleep when I was working at the workstation directly, but it does now. Does RDS system somehow override my power settings?

The workstation *is* joined to a Windows domain, but shouldn't then group policy override power settings as visible in the control panel applet?

This drives me nuts.

Comment: On the workstation at work, reinstall the Power Driver, restart, set Sleep when plugged in to "Never". Restart again and test. I have had a client machine set up like this and it never goes to sleep.

Comment: Which one is the "Power Driver"?

Comment: You would need to look up the drivers for the machine you are logging into .  You can go to Device Manager on the machine, system devices, There may not be a power driver for a desktop. If not, then I do not know how you would reset the components that control this settings.